# Computed array of objects list and reorder on date field change

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am listing an array of objects that is a computed value based on a preset prop containing a date field in each object that is a string and during initial rendering (I've preset some values for testing purposes) the child component instances are sorted and rendered properly but when I change the date in one of them after all is rendered, and set it to be earlier then the date in the instance before it (set **2019-02-15** to be **2019-02-04**) it is supposed to switch places with that item (in this case the instance with the date **2019-02-07**).

I've noticed that after I manually change a date, the computed property sorts the array elements properly but it is also invoked a second time and then the array that is sorted (legs prop) has the date that I've set manually duplicated - it has also become the date of the leg that is supposed to switch places with the one I've changed

Each object in the array is passed down to a component(Leg.vue) that takes the values and renders the instance of the "leg".

```
<v-form>
   <leg v-for="leg in orderedLegs" :leg="leg"></leg>
</v-form>

export default {
  name: 'SearchForm',
  components: {
    Leg
  },
  props: {
   legs: {
    type: Array,
    default: function () {
     return [
       { from: ["third"], to: [], date: "2019-02-20" },
       { from: ["second"], to: [], date: "2019-02-15"},
       { from: ["first"], to: [], date: "2019-02-07" }
     ]
    }
   }
  },

computed: {
  orderedLegs: function () {
    return this.legs.sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a['date']) - new 
Date(b['date']) })
  },
}
```

Comment: I'm almost certain this is due to the interaction of the `in place` sorting of `sort`, and Vue's trouble with recognizing array changes.  Try `return [...this.lens].sort()` in your computed property

Comment: you are also not setting a key, though this is recommended in `v-for` in order to prevent such troubles.

Comment: try to use watch with flag deep: on instead of computed.

Comment: @MarvinIrwin I've tried your method with the spread operator and for the initial loading of the page I got leg components sorted from the latest to the earliest date(which is the opposite of what I need) but when I change the date in one of the instances no sorting occurs, the computed property is not invoked at all

Comment: @NikolayVetrov When I try to change something that I am watching from inside the watcher it creates an infinite loop. Can you elaborate a bit more on how your solution can be implemented.

Comment: Why not just use `$forceUpdate` after `sort` function?

Comment: Can you provide a chunk of leg's component code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$forceUpdate` ([Vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate)) or `$nextTick` ([Vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)).

From docs about `$forceUpdate`:

> Force the Vue instance to re-render. Note it does not affect all child
> components, only the instance itself and child components with
> inserted slot content.

From docs about `$nextTick`:

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use
> it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM
> update. This is the same as the global Vue.nextTick, except that the
> callback’s this context is automatically bound to the instance calling
> this method.

Example:

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  methods: {
    // ...
    example: function () {
      // modify data
      this.message = 'changed'
      // DOM is not updated yet
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        // DOM is now updated
        // `this` is bound to the current instance
        this.doSomethingElse()
      })
    }
  }
})
```